# Integration using Stokes theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I do not fully understand how to use Stokes theorem to compute the following integral could someone show me in this example.

$$\int_C (x+2y)dx+(2z+2x)dy+(z+y)dz\,$$ $C$ is intersection of sphere $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 =1$ and plane $y=z$

Answer (score 2):

Stokes theorem says
$\oint f(r(t))\cdot dr = \iint \nabla\times f(x,y,z) dS$

Where S is any surface bounded by that contour.

$\nabla\times f(x,y,z) = (-1,0,0)$

Why don't we use disk on the plane y=z as our surface.  The normal to the plane is $(0,1,-1)$

and we can stop right there, as $\nabla\times f(x,y,z) \cdot n = 0$

Comment: can you explain further how you derived the normal and what parametrisation you used ?

Comment: I didn't get as far as finding a parameterization as it wasn't really necessary.  I probably would have gone with something line $x = r \cos \theta, y =r \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}\sin\theta, z = r\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \sin\theta$  However, whatever paramertization I choose the normal would me in the same direction.

Comment: right so what would be the vector product using that parameterization

Comment: Not at all necessary! but $dS = (\frac{\partial x}{\partial r},\frac{\partial y}{\partial r},\frac{\partial z}{\partial r})\times(\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta},\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta},\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}) = (\cos\theta,\frac {\sqrt2}{2}\sin\theta,\frac {\sqrt2}{2}\sin\theta)\times(-r\sin\theta, r\frac{\sqrt 2}2 \cos\theta,r\frac{\sqrt 2}2 \cos\theta) = (0,-r\frac {\sqrt 2}{2},r\frac {\sqrt 2}{2})\ dr\ d\theta\implies \nabla\times f \cdot n\ dS = 0$

Comment: okay i understand now thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using differential 1-form

$$\omega  = \left( {x + 2y} \right)dx + \left( {2z + 2x} \right)dy + \left( {z + y} \right)dz$$

we get for $z = y$

$$\omega  = \left( {x + 2y} \right)dx + \left( {2x + 4y} \right)dy$$

For exterior derivative, that is applying operator $d$, it follows

$$d\omega  = 2dy \wedge dx + 2dx \wedge dy$$

$$d\omega  =  - 2dx \wedge dy + 2dx \wedge dy = 0$$.

But know, from Stoke's theorem

$$\int\limits_{\partial S} \omega   = \int\limits_S {d\omega }  = 0$$

[image]